# What does the error "int object has no attribute __getitem__" mean for this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want a loop to create an array of 11 integers `y[i]` such that `y[i] = (i+1)*(i+2)` and it gives me an error which I don't understand.

```
In [100]: y = zeros(11)
     ...: for i in range(11):
     ...:     y[i] = (x[i]+1)*(x[i]+2)
     ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-7a762b788eff> in <module>()
      1 y = zeros(11)
      2 for i in range(11):
----> 3     y[i] = (x[i]+1)*(x[i]+2)
      4 

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Wait, your first sentence says `y[i] = (i+1)*(i+2)` but your code says `y[i] = (x[i]+1)*(x[i]+2)`.  One of those two must be wrong.

Comment: Where is x defined?  You need to show use more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is an integer, *not* an array:

```
>>> x = i = 0
>>> x[i]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

You need to scan back in your code and see what rebound `x` to an integer.

Your *question* however implies you think you are executing:

```
y[i] = (i+1)*(i+2)
```

but your actual code sample clearly shows you are not. Figure out which code should actually run here first.

Answer (score 1):

Basically that means, that you try to do `[]` on an `int` so `y` or `x` in your code is an `integer`